# How to dilate multiple line within an image with each line's slope?

Tags: matlab

How to dilate multiple line within an image (each line has known slope, & dilating `direction = SLOPE`)?

I need to dilate or increase the length of line. I know the SLOPE of the line. Dilation `direction = SLOPE`.

I tried imdilate from Matlab with `SE = ones(10,3)` which gives me dilation to all pixels. But, I want only in the end of each line.

This SE gives me vertical direction dilation, but I also need adaptive direction (i.e., direction is different for each line).

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?  Also, that logic of dilating with different structuring elements in multiple directions won't work.  Even if you use a structuring element in a different direction, you will still get pixels that get dilated.  As long as any elements from the structuring element touch an object pixel, you will experience dilation.

Comment: I would recommend you use something else to extend lines.... something like the Hough Transform would work.